# How to print "rendered node" version of Node Reference field in template?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I have two content types: Type A and Type B. I have a Node Reference field on content Type A (using [References](https://drupal.org/project/References) module) that is set to be displayed using the "Rendered Node" version of that referenced node. It references nodes of content Type B. How can I print the content of that field as a rendered node in a custom template file for content Type A?

Comment: what do you mean by "print the content of that field"? do you mean body field?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using https://drupal.org/project/References ?  I just want to edit the question, as how the field is stored varies between the various reference modules for Drupal 7.

Comment: @MPD - Good catch. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @MPD, yes, I am using References.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `$node` object, you will find the subordinate node object at `$node->field_fieldname['und'][0]['node']`. To render this in a page you have to turn it into a renderable array. You do this with `node_view()`,specifying the type of display mode. Try:

```
<?php
if(isset($node->field_fieldname['und'][0]['node'])) {
  $second_node = $node->field_fieldname['und'][0]['node'];
  $view_mode = 'teaser'; // or 'full' as the case may be
  $render_array = node_view( $second_node, $view_mode);
  print render($render_array);
}
?>
```

EDIT

MPD is correct. The above assumes that the field is a Node Reference field. If you are using an Entity Reference field, the code should be changed to:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($node->field_fieldname['und'][0]['entity'])) {
      $second_node = $node->field_fieldname['und'][0]['entity'];
      ...
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `target_id` and not `entity`?

Comment: @MPD - Node reference uses ['nid'] for the id and ['node'] for the object. Entity reference uses ['target_id'] for the id and ['entity'] for the object. The node (or entity) object is included in the field data. Why access the id and separately load the object when it is already there?

Comment: @Triskelion  Odd.  I have never seen anything other than ['target_id'] when I dpm() or print_r() a node.

Comment: @MPD - I have found that the global `$node` may be incomplete. When I do a `print_r()`, I usually precede it with `$full_node=node_load($node->nid)`. You would be amazed at the differences I find :-)